# Port Android Studio app to .NET UWP

Tags: c#, .net, android-studio, xamarin, uwp

I have a complex Android app which now needs to run on UWP.
I figured that I'll have to re-write and re-design most of it but I'm wondering if there's any way whatsoever that I can at least port some of it into .NET so that I have a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has been working on converting **Android** and **iOS** to UWP directly just like [`Desktop Bridge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root). And currently [**Windows Bridge for iOS**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/ios) has been used. It is a Microsoft open-source project that provides an Objective-C development environment for Visual Studio and support for iOS APIs. You could refer [**Move from iOS to UWP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/ios-to-uwp-root) for more detail. And Microsoft also provide Windows Bridge for Android. However, it has not finished.